# Check if a makefile exists before including it

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a makefile that includes a Rules.mak file that holds includes to tools I want to use. Problem is that the tools folder has free options if they want to extract a version or use the "native" installation. So I want to include the tools extracted rules if it exists otherwise I want to include the native file.

something like this is the goal:

```
if Tool/Rules.mak exists then
  include Tool/Rules.mak
else
  include common/Rules-Tool.mak
fi
```

I have tried either the bash way or the make way but as this is preincludes to setup the enviroment I don't have a specifik target but make calls out wrong due to the check fails.

```
if [ -f Tool/Rules.mak ]
then
echo testfile exists!
fi
```

also

```
if [ -d ./Tool ]
then
echo testfile exists!
fi
```

as well as versions with quotes and similar. Problem is that almost all the time when I type make I get the following error:

```
Rules.mak:14: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You could do it like that (no `if` or `else`)

```
-include Tool/Rules.mak
include common/Rules-Tool
```

like this you won't get an error if Tool/Rules.mak does not exists. (The '-' does the trick)

In common/Rules-Tool you then use the ?= operator ("conditional variable assignment operator") to assign values to the variable. This operator will assign the value only if the variable does not exists yet. IOW, it will not overwrite a pre-existing value. If Tool/Rules.mak does not exist or only partially fills in variable common/Rules-Tool will complete them.

Comment: The original solution doesn't work because it uses /bin/sh `if` statements instead of `GNU make` ones.

Answer (score 6):

If for some reason you don't want to use the `?=` operator, (perhaps you have more action than just setting the variable) then you can do the `if..then..else..fi` this way:

```
ifneq ("$(wildcard Tool/Rules.mak)","")
  $(info using Tools/Rules.mak)
  include Tool/Rules.mak
else
  $(info using common/Rules-Tool.mak)
  include common/Rules-Tool.mak
endif
```